# The type initializer for 'Lucene.Net.Store.FSDirectory' threw an exception' error

Tags: azure, lucene.net

I'm using the Azure Library for Lucene.net (ALL) to create and search indexes on my test Azure account.

Have setup blob storage and am able to access it using the Azure Portal and the Azure Storage Explorer.

Having issues with writing indexes to the blob storage as well as reading Lucene.net indexes that I created locally and manually moved up.

Seem to be going backwards because initially I was able to see that the ALL was able to create the write.lock, but first things first...

Now I'm getting an 'The type initializer for 'Lucene.Net.Store.FSDirectory' threw an exception' error.

I'm using the blob storage connection string as follows: DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http; AccountName=; AccountKey=;

Code failing on now is:

```
var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(BlobStorageConnectionString);
AzureDirectory azureDirectory = new AzureDirectory(account, indexByName);
```

Note: yes I should probably be reading from the config file; just trying to get it to work correctly and the account var seems valid.

Thoughts on what I should look into?

Comment: Can you also post the inner exception?

Comment: Do you have details on what the bad config entry was? I'm having a very similar problem and can't find it.